# BIRT Reporting: how to access LinkedHashMap in script

Tags: birt

While creating BIRT Report, I'm trying to access a LinkedHashMap in report beforeFactory event thro' rhino scripting..Able to print the map. But, when i use any method like size(), the following error is thrown

size not found

```
var test1 = reportVO.getTest();   // "test" is a LinkedHashMap
log(test1)                                 // --> In the logs, im able to see the LinkedHashMap contents printed
(log test1.size())                       // --> this fails.
```

I have imported the util package.

I read about org.eclipse.birt.core.script.NativeJavaLinkedHashMap. I tried accessing the LinkedHashMap thro' methods of this class also, like

```
test1.getIds()      // Method from NativeJavaLinkedHashMap --> this fails too
```

getIds not found

Is there a specific way to access LinkedhashMap in script.

Thanks,
 Vishnupriya

Answer (score 0):

Did you used test1.length ? you are now accessing javascript variable instead of java variable
[For More Click Here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/25610-passing-java-hashmap-to-report-as-report-parameter/)